# How to turn an array of arrays into a matrix in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

I want to turn a array of arrays into a matrix. To illustrate; let the array of arrays be:

```
[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

I would like to turn this into the 3x3 matrix:

```
[1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9]
```

How would you do this in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this. For instance, something along the lines of `vcat(transpose.(a)...)` will work as a one-liner

```
julia> a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
3-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2, 3]
 [4, 5, 6]
 [7, 8, 9]

julia> vcat(transpose.(a)...)
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9
```

though note that

1. Since your inner arrays are column-vectors as written, you need to `transpose` them all before you can vertically concatenate (aka `vcat`) them (either that or horizontally concatenate and then transpose the whole result after, i.e., `transpose(hcat(a...))`), and
2. The splatting operator `...` which makes this one-liner work will not be very efficient when applied to `Array`s in general, and especially not when applied to larger arrays-of-arrays.

Performance-wise for larger arrays-of-arrays, it will likely actually be hard to beat preallocating a result of the right size and then simply filling with a loop, e.g.

```
result = similar(first(a), length(a), length(first(a)))
for i=1:length(a)
    result[i,:] = a[i] # Aside: `=` is actually slightly faster than `.=` here, though either will have the same practical result in this case
end
```

Some quick benchmarks for reference:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @benchmark vcat(transpose.($a)...)
BechmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 405 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  241.289 ns …   3.994 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 92.59%
 Time  (median):     262.836 ns               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   289.105 ns ± 125.940 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.06% ±  4.61%

  ▁▆▇█▇▆▅▅▅▄▄▄▄▃▂▂▂▃▃▂▂▁▁▁▂▄▃▁▁ ▁                             ▁ ▂
  ████████████████████████████████▇▆▅▆▆▄▆▆▆▄▄▃▅▅▃▄▆▄▁▃▃▃▅▄▁▃▅██ █
  241 ns        Histogram: log(frequency) by time        534 ns <

 Memory estimate: 320 bytes, allocs estimate: 5.

julia> @benchmark for i=1:length($a)
           $result[i,:] = $a[i]
       end
BechmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 993 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  33.966 ns … 124.918 ns  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     36.710 ns               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   39.795 ns ±   7.566 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  ▄▄██▄▅▃ ▅▃ ▄▁▂ ▂▁▂▅▂▁    ▄▂▁                                 ▂
  ██████████████▇██████▆█▇▆███▆▇███▇▆▆▅▆▅▅▄▄▅▄▆▆▆▄▁▃▄▁▃▄▅▅▃▁▄█ █
  34 ns         Histogram: log(frequency) by time      77.7 ns <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```

In general, filling column-by-column (if possible) will be faster than filling row-by-row as we have done here, since Julia is column-major.

Comment: Thank you! I used your loop suggestion as my arrays are indeed very big. I am quite new to Julia (programming in general) and programming for the optimization of speed/performance is new to me. Would you have any suggestions for resources to learn about this?

Comment: The documentations's [performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/) are a great resource to visit regularly.

Comment: Yeah, and @benchmark things when in doubt. In many cases if performance is important you might check out LoopVectorization.jl, which when applied to type-stable, non-allocating, non-branching, reorderable loops will generally be faster than anything else around

Comment: Also in general _type stability_ is a particularly common “gotcha” when coming from other languages

Comment: Thank you guys for your help! I will look into those tips

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @cbk's answer, another (slightly more efficient) one-liner is

```
julia> transpose(reduce(hcat, a))
3×3 transpose(::Matrix{Int64}) with eltype Int64:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

# or

reshape(1:9, 3, 3)' # remember that ' makes the transpose of a Matrix
```